# Getting the relevancy value in solr and multiply with one field and sort with that

Tags: solr

Is is possible to get the relevancy score and multiply with some value in an field and sort with that field

say the relevancy of the returned document is 0.8 and i have field score and it has 3 i need to multiply with that field 0.8*3=2.4 so i need to sort with that highest field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [ExtendedDisMax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax), then you can use the `boost` parameter as explained [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#boost_.28Boost_Function.2C_multiplicative.29).